# Install sql server express database engine only

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, sql-server-express

I am deploying a wpf application that requires sql server 2008 as a prerequisite. As a result I am embedding the sql server installer in my application. When that launches the SQL Server Installation  window shows up:
[image]

I don't want the user to have to go through out this installation. That program will install SQL Express and many other things like SQL Management Studio.

**Is there a place where I can download SQL Express 2008 the database engine only? so that the user will just have to click next, Agree, Ok... etc... without having to make complicated decisions. Or maybe is it possible to install sql server express throughout the command line?**

I am including the installer in my application because my application is supposed to be able to be installed without having an interenet connection. Also I cannto seem to find a place where I can download SQL Server express the database engine only.

Comment: Incidentally, leaving out the client tools could result in a support nightmare for you (or just general nightmares for the client)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go [here](http://www.microsoft.com/betaexperience/pd/SQLEXP08V2/enus/) and download the appropriate version of SQL Express. Then see the [How to: Install SQL Server 2008 R2 Using a Configuration File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239405.aspx) article on MSDN. Note that after you generate the config file for the installation, changing the following keys in the config will probably be of particular interest to you:

```
; Setup will not display any user interface. 

QUIET="False"

; Setup will display progress only without any user interaction. 

QUIETSIMPLE="True"

; Automatically accept the license terms

IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms="True"
```

Comment: James I been trying all this time to create my configuration file and I get a bunch of errors. I created a similar question in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122477/install-sql-server-express-r2-2008-using-a-configuration-file  that asks on how to create that file. Maybe you can help. You already help me a lot anyways. thanks...

Comment: Hi @TonoNam, I added an answer to your other question.